# POST REST API calling a function with parameters

Tags: node.js, rest, express

In my index.js I have this

```
app.post("/token", function (req, res) {
  var token = req.body
  createToken(token);
});
```

Which is being exported by token.js

```
const createToken = (token) = (req, res) => {
    console.log("Creating Token", token);
}
```

In my console the display is:
*Creating Token [Function: token]*

Why is the value of the *token* not being passed?
But if the token.js has this,

```
const createToken = (token) => {
    console.log("Creating Token", token);
}
```

it is working.

But I'll be needing res so I can do a res.send. Am I doing it wrong?

Thanks in advance and happy holidays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna add res in your function, it's so simple, do this:

```
app.post("/token", (req, res) => {
  var token = req.body
  createToken(token, res);
});
```

and

```
const createToken = (token, res) => {
  console.log("Creating Token", token);
  res.send({token})
}
```